# Unable to install luasnip

Tags: neovim, lua, packer, plugin-luasnip

After installing `luasnip` I encountered this error:

[image]
[image]

Even though `cmp` is already installed

**Plugins.lua**

```
use({ "onsails/lspkind-nvim", event = "VimEnter" })

use({ "L3MON4D3/LuaSnip", after = 'nvim-cmp', })

-- auto-completion engine
use({ "hrsh7th/nvim-cmp", after = "lspkind-nvim", config = [[require('config.nvim-cmp')]], requires = { { "saadparwaiz1/cmp_luasnip" } },})

use({ "saadparwaiz1/cmp_luasnip" })

use ({"hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lua",after = "cmp_luasnip",})

use({ "hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp", after = "nvim-cmp" })
use({ "hrsh7th/cmp-path", after = "nvim-cmp" })
use({ "hrsh7th/cmp-buffer", after = "nvim-cmp" })
use({ "hrsh7th/cmp-omni", after = "nvim-cmp" })

use({ "neovim/nvim-lspconfig", after = "cmp-nvim-lsp", config = [[require('config.lsp')]] })
use({ "rafamadriz/friendly-snippets" })
```

`Nvim version: 0.8.1`

[Nvim-config](https://github.com/Rohith-JN/nvim-config)

Answer (score 1):

I'd remove the `after` attribute of Luasnip as shown in the [README](https://github.com/saadparwaiz1/cmp_luasnip#cmp_luasnip) of `cmp_luasnip`:

```lua
 use "L3MON4D3/LuaSnip"
```

### Edit 1

```lua
        use({
            "hrsh7th/nvim-cmp",
            config = [[require('config.nvim-cmp')]],
            requires = {
                "saadparwaiz1/cmp_luasnip",
                "hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lua",
                "hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp",
                "hrsh7th/cmp-path",
                "hrsh7th/cmp-buffer",
                "hrsh7th/cmp-omni",
            },
        })
```

Copy+paste this and replace with [this part](https://github.com/Rohith-JN/nvim-config/blob/master/lua/plugins.lua#L51-L64) of your config.

Comment: That fixed the `luasnip not found` error but I am still getting `module cmp not found`

Comment: I edited my answer, try it with my edit

Comment: That did not resolve the issue

Comment: Should I open an issue in [LuaSnip](https://github.com/L3MON4D3/LuaSnip)?

Comment: Are you still getting the same errors?

Comment: Yes I am getting: `module 'cmp' not found`

Comment: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/saadparwaiz1/cmp_luasnip/issues/56)

Comment: `module 'cmp' not found` is a different error and it has nothing to do with the LuaSnip plugin. It seems like that you're structuring your plugins wrong.

Comment: It occurred when I added `luasnip` and `cmp_luasnip`, I arranged them in the order specified by the documentation.